# Parse vcard json C#

Tags: c#, json, vcf-vcard

I want to parse the vcard RFC 7095 using Json.NET :

```
["vcard",
     [
       ["version", {}, "text", "4.0"],
       ["fn", {}, "text", "John Doe"],
       ["gender", {}, "text", "M"],
       ["categories", {}, "text", "computers", "cameras"],
       ...
     ]
   ]
```

I try to do it using FormatTypeFormater but I cannot validate the json.

Comment: Show some code, and the error message you are getting

Comment: Because that isn't a JSON object, it's a JSON array. It's probably expecting `"key":"value"` pairs. If Json.NET doesn't support JSON arrays as top-level objects you might get away with it as a set of nested arrays if you wrap the whole thing in a `{"jcard": ... }`, i.e. add an outermost object. (Is Json.NET serialization based?)

Comment: IMO that RFC is horrible. A vCard is structured data in key-value form, and JSON is naturally key-value. Yet instead we've got some horrid abuse of arrays. May it quickly get squashed by something better.

Comment: @Rup A key/value JSON object wouldn't quite work.  It's possible to have multiple instances of the same vCard property (e.g. ADR).

Comment: @Michael OK, so make key "address"'s value be an array of structured addresses, or either a single address object or an array as appropriate and you can tell from the type (which I'm not fond of really, but there's precedent in JavaScript structures). Better yet, mandate each address has a unique (home, office, etc.) and use key-key-value (OK, will need flags to represent priorities though). At first glance your parser stores data as a key-value map from property type to array of values, each of which is a structure: why not just serialise that to make the JSON? That would be better than this.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it using `JavaScriptSerializer` to a `object[]`, then work on it to build a better complex type:

```
 var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var o = (object[])js.Deserialize(@"[""vcard"",
   [
     [""version"", {}, ""text"", ""4.0""],
     [""fn"", {}, ""text"", ""John Doe""],
     [""gender"", {}, ""text"", ""M""],
     [""categories"", {}, ""text"", ""computers"", ""cameras""]
   ]
 ]", typeof(object[]));



if (o.length > 1 && (o[0] as string) == "vcard")
{
    var props = o[1] as object[];

    foreach (object[] values in props)
    {
        switch (values[0] as string)
        {
            case "version":
                ...
                break;
            case "fn":
                ...
                break;
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

You should implmenet more validation on this, but this is a good start..