# Parsing JSON WHOIS data from ARIN

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, vcf-vcard

I'm working on a way to "automate" my log review process, and part of the (intended) process involves doing a WHOIS lookup of unknown IP addresses.  I've figured out how to pull the information from ARIN in JSON format, and I've almost gotten the entire object constructed and populated now.  However, I'm running into a problem with one particular nested object - the `vcardArray` object under the `entities`.

I'm using [Newtonsoft's Json.NET library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize the object(s) in the JSON response from the ARIN server.  Most of the information will deserialize correctly, but the section I'm failing to correctly parse is this:

```
"vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Cox Communications Inc." ], [ "adr", {
      "label" : "1400 Lake Hearn Dr.\nAtlanta\nGA\n30319\nUNITED STATES"
    }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "org" ] ] ]
```

When I comment out the `vcardArray` property in my `Entity` object, the rest of the JSON text parses without error.  But, since I don't know how to structure the properties of the `vCard` object, it will throw an exception if I try to use it.  I've tried defining it simply as a `List(Of String)`, but that fails when it tries to parse the "sub-arrays" in the JSON.  I even tried making it a `List(Of List(Of String))`, but then it throws an exception when it tries to parse the single string values.

I (obviously) haven't done a whole lot of work with JSON yet, so I'm not sure how I should structure my `vCard` object to accommodate the lack of actual key/value pairs *AND* nested array objects in this section.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**VB.NET code:**

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Public Class WHOIS
    Private SearchIP As IPAddress

#Region "JSON CLASS OBJECTS"
    Public Class ARINDetail
        Public Property rdapConformance As List(Of String)
        Public Property notices As List(Of Notice)
        Public Property handle As String
        Public Property startAddress As String
        Public Property endAddress As String
        Public Property ipVersion As String
        Public Property name As String
        Public Property type As String
        Public Property country As String
        Public Property parentHandle As String
        Public Property objectClassName As String
        Public Property entities As List(Of Entity)
        Public Property events As List(Of [Event])
        Public Property remarks As List(Of Remark)
        Public Property links As List(Of Link)
    End Class

    Public Class Notice
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property description As List(Of String)
        Public Property links As List(Of Link)
    End Class

    Public Class Entity
        Public Property handle As String
        Public Property vcardArray As List(Of vCard)
        Public Property roles As List(Of String)
        Public Property remarks As List(Of Remark)
        Public Property objectClassName As String
        Public Property links As List(Of Link)
        Public Property events As List(Of [Event])
        Public Property entities As List(Of Entity)
    End Class

    Public Class [Event]
        Public Property eventAction As String
        Public Property eventdate As String
    End Class

    Public Class Remark
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property description As List(Of String)
    End Class

    Public Class vCard
        ' ** THIS IS THE CLASS I CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO CONSTRUCT
    End Class

    Public Class Link
        Public Property value As String
        Public Property rel As String
        Public Property href As String
        Public Property type As String
    End Class
#End Region

#Region "CONSTRUCTORS"
    Public Sub New(ByVal IP As String)
        Try
            SearchIP = IPAddress.Parse(IP)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ArgumentException("The IP address provided is invalid")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal IP As IPAddress)
        SearchIP = IP
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "PUBLIC METHODS"
    Public Function GetWHOISData() As String
        Dim ARINJSON As String = String.Empty

        ARINJSON = RequestARINData()

        Dim Details As ARINDetail = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ARINDetail)(ARINJSON)

    End Function
#End Region

#Region "PRIVATE METHODS"
    Private Function RequestARINData() As String
        Dim RequestURL As String = "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/" & Me.SearchIP.ToString
        Dim JSONResponse As String = String.Empty
        Dim HTTPResponse As System.Net.WebResponse
        Dim HTTPRequest As System.Net.WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(RequestURL)

        HTTPResponse = HTTPRequest.GetResponse

        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(HTTPResponse.GetResponseStream)
            JSONResponse = sr.ReadToEnd
            sr.Close()
        End Using

        Return JSONResponse
    End Function
#End Region
End Class
```

**Full JSON Response from ARIN**

```
{
  "rdapConformance" : [ "rdap_level_0" ],
  "notices" : [ {
    "title" : "Terms of Service",
    "description" : [ "By using the ARIN RDAP/Whois service, you are agreeing to the RDAP/Whois Terms of Use" ],
    "links" : [ {
      "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
      "rel" : "about",
      "type" : "text/html",
      "href" : "https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html"
    } ]
  } ],
  "handle" : "NET-68-15-96-0-1",
  "startAddress" : "068.015.096.000",
  "endAddress" : "068.015.127.255",
  "ipVersion" : "v4",
  "name" : "NETBLK-OK-CBS-68-15-96-0",
  "parentHandle" : "NET-68-0-0-0-1",
  "remarks" : [ {
    "title" : "Registration Comments",
    "description" : [ "For legal requests/assistance please use the following contact information:", "", "Cox Subpoena Phone: 404-269-0100", "", "Cox Subpoena Info: http://www.cox.com/policy/leainformation/default.asp" ]
  } ],
  "events" : [ {
    "eventAction" : "last changed",
    "eventDate" : "2007-03-27T13:14:28-04:00"
  }, {
    "eventAction" : "registration",
    "eventDate" : "2002-04-21T00:00:00-04:00"
  } ],
  "links" : [ {
    "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
    "rel" : "self",
    "type" : "application/rdap+json",
    "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/068.015.096.000"
  }, {
    "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
    "rel" : "alternate",
    "type" : "application/xml",
    "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-68-15-96-0-1"
  }, {
    "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
    "rel" : "up",
    "type" : "application/rdap+json",
    "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/068.000.000.000/12"
  } ],
  "entities" : [ {
    "handle" : "CXA",
    "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Cox Communications Inc." ], [ "adr", {
      "label" : "1400 Lake Hearn Dr.\nAtlanta\nGA\n30319\nUNITED STATES"
    }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "org" ] ] ],
    "roles" : [ "registrant" ],
    "remarks" : [ {
      "title" : "Registration Comments",
      "description" : [ "For legal requests/assistance please use the\r", "following contact information:\r", "Cox Subpoena Info: https://www.cox.com/aboutus/policies/law-enforcement-and-subpoenas-information.html" ]
    } ],
    "links" : [ {
      "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
      "rel" : "self",
      "type" : "application/rdap+json",
      "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/CXA"
    }, {
      "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
      "rel" : "alternate",
      "type" : "application/xml",
      "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/CXA"
    } ],
    "events" : [ {
      "eventAction" : "last changed",
      "eventDate" : "2017-05-30T09:52:56-04:00"
    } ],
    "entities" : [ {
      "handle" : "BERUB3-ARIN",
      "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "adr", {
        "label" : "6305-A Peachtree Dunwoody Road,\nAtlanta\nGA\n30328\nUNITED STATES"
      }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Tori Berube" ], [ "n", { }, "text", [ "Berube", "Tori", "", "", "" ] ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "individual" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "tori.berube@cox.com" ], [ "tel", {
        "type" : [ "work", "voice" ]
      }, "text", "+1-404-269-4416" ] ] ],
      "roles" : [ "administrative", "technical" ],
      "links" : [ {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "self",
        "type" : "application/rdap+json",
        "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/BERUB3-ARIN"
      }, {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "alternate",
        "type" : "application/xml",
        "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/BERUB3-ARIN"
      } ],
      "events" : [ {
        "eventAction" : "last changed",
        "eventDate" : "2017-04-04T08:47:01-04:00"
      }, {
        "eventAction" : "registration",
        "eventDate" : "2014-03-18T13:16:56-04:00"
      } ],
      "status" : [ "validated" ],
      "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
      "objectClassName" : "entity"
    }, {
      "handle" : "MEROL3-ARIN",
      "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "adr", {
        "label" : "6305-A Peachtree Dunwoody Rd\nAtlanta\nGA\n30328\nUNITED STATES"
      }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Cari Merola" ], [ "n", { }, "text", [ "Merola", "Cari", "", "", "" ] ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "individual" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "cari.merola@cox.com" ], [ "tel", {
        "type" : [ "work", "voice" ]
      }, "text", "+1-404-269-4416" ] ] ],
      "roles" : [ "technical" ],
      "links" : [ {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "self",
        "type" : "application/rdap+json",
        "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/MEROL3-ARIN"
      }, {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "alternate",
        "type" : "application/xml",
        "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/MEROL3-ARIN"
      } ],
      "events" : [ {
        "eventAction" : "last changed",
        "eventDate" : "2017-05-10T10:37:30-04:00"
      }, {
        "eventAction" : "registration",
        "eventDate" : "2017-05-10T10:37:30-04:00"
      } ],
      "status" : [ "validated" ],
      "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
      "objectClassName" : "entity"
    }, {
      "handle" : "ADA131-ARIN",
      "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "adr", {
        "label" : "6305 Peachtree dunwoody\nAtlanta\nGA\n30328\nUNITED STATES"
      }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Alvin Demond Anderson" ], [ "n", { }, "text", [ "Anderson", "Alvin", "Demond", "", "" ] ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "individual" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "alvin.anderson@cox.com" ], [ "tel", {
        "type" : [ "work", "voice" ]
      }, "text", "+1-404-269-4416" ] ] ],
      "roles" : [ "technical" ],
      "links" : [ {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "self",
        "type" : "application/rdap+json",
        "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/ADA131-ARIN"
      }, {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "alternate",
        "type" : "application/xml",
        "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/ADA131-ARIN"
      } ],
      "events" : [ {
        "eventAction" : "last changed",
        "eventDate" : "2016-08-30T17:24:55-04:00"
      }, {
        "eventAction" : "registration",
        "eventDate" : "2014-09-09T13:19:41-04:00"
      } ],
      "status" : [ "validated" ],
      "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
      "objectClassName" : "entity"
    }, {
      "handle" : "RWA196-ARIN",
      "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "adr", {
        "label" : "1400 Lake Hearn Dr.\nAtlanta\nGA\n30319\nUNITED STATES"
      }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Roderick Waldron" ], [ "n", { }, "text", [ "Waldron", "Roderick", "", "", "" ] ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "individual" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "abuse@cox.net" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "Roderick.Waldron@cox.com" ], [ "tel", {
        "type" : [ "work", "voice" ]
      }, "text", "+1-404-269-7626" ] ] ],
      "roles" : [ "technical" ],
      "links" : [ {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "self",
        "type" : "application/rdap+json",
        "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/RWA196-ARIN"
      }, {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "alternate",
        "type" : "application/xml",
        "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/RWA196-ARIN"
      } ],
      "events" : [ {
        "eventAction" : "last changed",
        "eventDate" : "2016-11-22T12:32:08-05:00"
      }, {
        "eventAction" : "registration",
        "eventDate" : "2009-04-24T10:54:11-04:00"
      } ],
      "status" : [ "validated" ],
      "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
      "objectClassName" : "entity"
    }, {
      "handle" : "NIA16-ARIN",
      "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "adr", {
        "label" : "6305-A Peachtree Dunwoody\nAtlanta\nGA\n30328\nUNITED STATES"
      }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "National IP Administrator" ], [ "org", { }, "text", "National IP Administrator" ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "group" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "tiffany.coleman@cox.com" ], [ "tel", {
        "type" : [ "work", "voice" ]
      }, "text", "+1-404-269-4416" ] ] ],
      "roles" : [ "technical" ],
      "remarks" : [ {
        "title" : "Unvalidated POC",
        "description" : [ "ARIN has attempted to validate the data for this POC, but has received no response from the POC since 2015-09-09" ]
      } ],
      "links" : [ {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "self",
        "type" : "application/rdap+json",
        "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/NIA16-ARIN"
      }, {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "alternate",
        "type" : "application/xml",
        "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/NIA16-ARIN"
      } ],
      "events" : [ {
        "eventAction" : "last changed",
        "eventDate" : "2014-09-09T13:19:45-04:00"
      }, {
        "eventAction" : "registration",
        "eventDate" : "2014-09-09T13:19:45-04:00"
      } ],
      "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
      "objectClassName" : "entity"
    }, {
      "handle" : "BAABO-ARIN",
      "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "adr", {
        "label" : "1400 Lake Hearn Drive\nAtlanta\nGA\n30342\nUNITED STATES"
      }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Aboubakr BA" ], [ "n", { }, "text", [ "BA", "Aboubakr", "", "", "" ] ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "individual" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "abuse@cox.net" ], [ "tel", {
        "type" : [ "work", "voice" ]
      }, "text", "+1-404-269-4416" ] ] ],
      "roles" : [ "technical" ],
      "remarks" : [ {
        "title" : "Unvalidated POC",
        "description" : [ "ARIN has attempted to validate the data for this POC, but has received no response from the POC since 2016-03-29" ]
      } ],
      "links" : [ {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "self",
        "type" : "application/rdap+json",
        "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/BAABO-ARIN"
      }, {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "alternate",
        "type" : "application/xml",
        "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/BAABO-ARIN"
      } ],
      "events" : [ {
        "eventAction" : "last changed",
        "eventDate" : "2015-03-30T11:27:55-04:00"
      }, {
        "eventAction" : "registration",
        "eventDate" : "2012-09-27T12:04:18-04:00"
      } ],
      "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
      "objectClassName" : "entity"
    }, {
      "handle" : "IC146-ARIN",
      "vcardArray" : [ "vcard", [ [ "version", { }, "text", "4.0" ], [ "adr", {
        "label" : "1400 Lake Hearn Drive\nAtlanta\nGA\n30319\nUNITED STATES"
      }, "text", [ "", "", "", "", "", "", "" ] ], [ "fn", { }, "text", "Cox Communications Inc" ], [ "org", { }, "text", "Cox Communications Inc" ], [ "kind", { }, "text", "group" ], [ "email", { }, "text", "abuse@cox.net" ], [ "tel", {
        "type" : [ "work", "voice" ]
      }, "text", "+1-404-269-7626" ] ] ],
      "roles" : [ "abuse" ],
      "remarks" : [ {
        "title" : "Unvalidated POC",
        "description" : [ "ARIN has attempted to validate the data for this POC, but has received no response from the POC since 2016-11-19" ]
      } ],
      "links" : [ {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "self",
        "type" : "application/rdap+json",
        "href" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/IC146-ARIN"
      }, {
        "value" : "https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/68.15.102.5",
        "rel" : "alternate",
        "type" : "application/xml",
        "href" : "https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/IC146-ARIN"
      } ],
      "events" : [ {
        "eventAction" : "last changed",
        "eventDate" : "2015-11-20T08:52:56-05:00"
      }, {
        "eventAction" : "registration",
        "eventDate" : "2002-02-12T11:20:45-05:00"
      } ],
      "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
      "objectClassName" : "entity"
    } ],
    "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
    "objectClassName" : "entity"
  } ],
  "port43" : "whois.arin.net",
  "objectClassName" : "ip network"
}
```

**EDIT:** I went on vacation for a week with no Internet connection, so I haven't had a chance to look into this very much since I posted the question.  Now that I'm back with a (somewhat) clear head, though, I've started doing some more research on exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

Through my liberal use of Google-fu, I've run across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278659/parse-vcard-json-c-sharp) which seems to give a similar answer to what @dbc posted in the comments below.  *However*, I *also* found that the vCards actually have a JSON equivalent - the jCard - as defined by [RFC 7095](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7095) (released in January 2014), which makes me believe that there should definitely be an easier way to deserialize them.  Obviously, the JSON that's giving me issues looks like an array of these jCard objects, so I just need to find a "standard" way to deserialize a jCard so that I can throw it in there. Then, I should be able to simply declare the `vcardArray` object as a `List(Of jCard)`, and I'm all set.

I'm doing some updates on my development system right now, so I'll have to take a closer look when that's done, but it seems to me that the Newtonsoft JSON library should have a `jCard` object by now.

I'm still researching, and I'll post another edit when I have more information, but I figured I'd post this and see if anyone has any thoughts or other tips based on what I've found so far.

Comment: Ugh, I think I would just do `Public Property vcardArray As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken` and let Json.NET parse that as free-form [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) data.

Comment: @dbc - Thank you for the tip.  That at least lets me pull the data into my `Entity` object without throwing an exception, which is a good start.  I'll see what else I can do with it from there.

Comment: Since I'm specifically dealing with Json.NET, I went ahead and added the `json.net` tag.  Also, since there is currently no jCard tag, and I don't have the reputation to add a new tag, and apparently a jCard is basically just a JSON representation of a vCard, I also added the `vcard` tag.